# XmlDocument garbled when opening and saving via StreamReader/StreamWriter

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, .net-4.5, filestream

I have a WinForms application in C# that uses XML configuration files.

To prevent other apps and users to edit those files while the app is running I use...

To open document:

```
document = new XmlDocument();

using ( var xr = new StreamReader( new FileStream( fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read ), Encoding.UTF8 ) )
{
    document.Load( xr );
}
```

...a Save() method that uses the writer to save the file again.

```
lock ( syncLock )
{
    using ( var writer = XmlTextWriter.Create( new FileStream( fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read ), settings ) )
    {
        document.Save( writer );
    }
}
```

The lock is there since multiple threads may want to save to the file. I'm actually not sure if that is making any sense at this end.

When I, for isntance, remove a node from the DOM tree and then save the file, the file becomes garbage.

This nice file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<history>
  <period something="2013-01-01 04:55:12" added="2013-01-01 04:58:12" />
  <period something="2013-01-01 10:55:12" added="2013-01-01 10:58:12" />
  <period something="2013-01-01 16:55:12" added="2013-01-01 16:58:12" />
  <period something="2013-01-01 22:55:12" added="2013-01-01 22:58:12" />
  <period something="2013-01-02 04:55:12" added="2013-01-02 04:58:12" />
  <period something="2013-01-02 10:55:12" added="2013-01-02 10:58:12" />
  <period something="2013-01-02 16:55:12" added="2013-01-02 16:58:12" />
  <period something="2013-01-02 22:55:12" added="2013-01-02 22:58:12" />
</history>
```

...becomes this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<history>
  <period something="2013-01-01 04:55:12" added="2013-01-01 04:58:12" />
  <period something="2013-01-01 10:55:12" added="2013-01-01 10:58:12" />
  <period something="2013-01-01 16:55:12" added="2013-01-01 16:58:12" />
  <period something="2013-01-01 22:55:12" added="2013-01-01 22:58:12" />
  <period something="2013-01-02 04:55:12" added="2013-01-02 04:58:12" />
  <period something="2013-01-02 10:55:12" added="2013-01-02 10:58:12" />
  <period something="2013-01-02 16:55:12" added="2013-01-02 16:58:12" />
</history>/>
    <period something="2013-01-02 22:55:12" added="2013-01-02 22:58:12" />
</history>
```

So the node I deleted is back, but the document is no longer well formed.

Why?
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
new FileStream( fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite )
```

If the file already exists, that will overwrite the existing file, but will *not* truncate it.

You should specify `FileMode.Create`... or more simply, just use [`File.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to obtain the stream. Even better, don't bother with `StreamWriter` or `StreamReaer`, or even manually creating the stream. Heck, when *loading* the file you can just specify the filename:

```
document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(fileName);
```

And for saving, if you really need the custom settings:

```
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(fileName, settings))
{
    document.Save(writer);
}
```

I would *strongly* suggest that you prevent reading from the file while you're writing it, by the way - while it's being written, it won't be a valid XML file anyway.

I'd also encourage you to migrate from `XmlDocument` to LINQ to XML (`XDocument` etc) if you possibly can - it's a much nicer API.

Comment: Thanks Jon that fixed it!
I want to migrate to LINQ but I am losing Xpath which I use heavily at least in this app.

Comment: @John: You can still use XPath in LINQ to XML - although I personally usually query the tree with `Elements` etc combined with `Where` clauses.